# How to create windows installer file using c# with Serial key and email validation

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I want to create a msi file using c#.net. The application is just like this

When the application installing a custom box will be appear showing serial key and email address. These values are checked with the database. If the email address and serial key are match, the installation start.

Please  help....